# Java character to represent all characters

Tags: java, character, special-characters

I've searched, but all methods i found did not work.

I've got a file with

```
    Arm.addBox( -2.5F, -2F, -3.09F, 5, 10, 6);
    ShoulderPlate.addBox( -0.5F, -1F, -5.5F, 5, 2, 1);
    Shoulder_Arm.addBox( -2.5F, -1F, -0.5F, 5, 2, 1);
    ... (Many more)
```

I've got the code

```
    public void readFile()
{
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        String a = scan.nextLine();

        if(a.contains("addBox"))
        {
            String b = a.replace("[ANY STING OF CHARACTERS].addBox", "addBox");
            System.out.printf("%s\n", b);
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I want this code to remove all the prefix names in front of the "addBox"

but in the line

```
            String b = a.replace("[ANY STING OF CHARACTERS].addBox", "addBox");
```

I have no idea what should replace '[ANY STING OF CHARACTERS]', such as [a-zA-Z] and apparently '.' is suppost to be all characters, and i'm suppost to use '.' for a fullstop

But this is not the case, and dose not work for me

If someone could tell me as to what i should be using

also, if someone could direct me to a list of all similar character tricks, that would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` simply replace the correspond String, and `replaceAll` is for regex.
Like this:

```
a.replaceAll(".*\\.addBox", "addBox");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using this:

```
 String b  = a.substring(a.indexOf(".addBox") + 1 ,a.length());
```

instead of

```
    String b = a.replace("[ANY STING OF CHARACTERS].addBox", "addBox");
```